# Can't run node server with babel

Tags: cmd, babeljs

I just started to learn nodejs with react and I'm following a tutorial of lynda. Well, it didin't take that long and I'm stuck. And I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.

My File structure:

- server.js
- config.js
- /node_modules

My config.js has the following content:

```
console.log("config");
```

My server.js file:

```
import './config';
```

So you see, nothing complicated there. Just basics. Now in the tutorial, they run the server.js file using babel, because of the new import syntax. He uses the following line on the cmd:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js
```

And here I get the problem. My CMD tells me:

> The command "." is either written wrong or can't be found.

(May not exactly this, I'm running my windows in german, so I don't know how it would be in english).

**What I've checked:**

I have a babel-node & babel-node.cmd file in the node_modules/.bin located in the same directory as my whole project. I try to run the command from the project directory. I just tried for hours now and I've no idea whats going wrong here. I would be really happy if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong... I've done exactly the same as the guy in the tutorial and it just works fine for him.

Thank you very much and have a nice day! :)

Comment: `cmd` usually refers to Windows, so shouldn't that be: `.\node_modules\.bin\babel-node.cmd ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OMG that brainlag I had here. Thats exactly the problem when you only develop on mac. Solved the problem perfectly. If you wish you can post it as answer, I'll upvote & accept.

Answer (score 2):

Running nodejs on windows is very challenging. A very difficult part is the path separator. For example, for your server.js file on Windows:

```
import '.\config';
```

Running part should be adjusted as well:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\babel-node.cmd server.js
```

If this still doesn't work, try to add the full file path before `server.js`

Before doing anything above, double check if babel-cli is installed:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```